# How to catch exception in asynchronously invoked action in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous

I have some blocking task which throws exceptions, for example:

```
public static string DummyFunction(string msg = "Dummy Funciton", int seconds = 2, string retval = null, Exception exception = null)
    {
        if (exception != null)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + msg);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("End: " + msg);
        return retval;
    }
```

I call this method asynchronously, but how can I catch the exception?

```
try
        {
            Action act6 = () => DummyFunction("act6 throws exception", exception: new Exception("thrown by act6"));
            var ar6 = act6.BeginInvoke(null, null);
            ar6.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Cannot reach here.
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e);
        }
```

Comment: I believe the exception will be thrown from `EndInvoke` if you call it.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that it makes no sense at all to invoke a delegate asynchronously and then just wait in the invoking thread for the asynchronous execution to complete. One hopes your real-world code is not like the code you posted here.

Comment: @slawekwin, I can't catch the exception by `try`ing around `EndInvoke`.

Comment: @RichardDong why you can't?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the action with a `Try..catch` :

```
Action act6 = 
() =>
{ 
   try
   {
       DummyFunction("act6 throws exception", exception: new Exception("thrown by act6")); 
   }
   catch(exception ex)
   {
      // Do something
   }

};
```

Alternatively, you can use `try.. catch` inside `DummyFunction` but it was trivial that you don't want to do that.